# Getting user selections on clicking browser back button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

My application has got several pages. On some pages I have given a back button on other pages it's not given (client's requirement). Now on a particular page, I have a list of choices (choices are image slides using jQuery plugin) to be selected by the user. Selecting a choice takes the user to next page. And now I want to get the same page with same selected choice as highlighted on clicking the browsers back button. On clicking the browsers back button, I guess the page is reloading loosing the cookie values i.e. when I select an image from my image set it takes me to another page. On clicking the browser back button, I wanted to get that page with same image selected from that set.Is there any work around so that I can get the selected values also on browser back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another plugin do that:

jQuery BBQ leverages the HTML5 hashchange event to allow simple, yet powerful bookmarkable #hash history. In addition, jQuery BBQ provides a full .deparam() method, along with both hash state management, and fragment / query string parse and merge utility methods.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the `onunload` event, which almost all major browsers* will fire, when the back/forward/refresh button is used. Let the `onunload` event handler synchronously send an AJAX request, containing all the values needed to restore the current page state, to a PHP script:

```
$(window).unload(function() {

    // Insert your code here to collect all values
    // necessary to save a restorable state of the
    // current page.
    //
    // var pageState = {
    //     page: host.pathname,
    //     :
    // };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "http://mydomain.com/mysave.php",
        data: jQuery.param(pageState),
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // your code
        }
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // your code
        }
    });  

});
```

Let the PHP script save the received page state somewhere (e.g. session, database, etc.), so it's available, when you're about to generate a page you would like to be restored to a previous state.

Be aware, that this solution has a possible disadvantage.

The synchronous request is used to give the server a real chance to receive and process the request completely. An asynchronous request would return immediately, thus already loading the new page and *maybe* cancelling the asynchronous request running in parallel, before it has been completed (or even sent).

Otoh synchronous requests block (freeze the browser, user cannot do anything) until the server responds. In case your server does not respond, this would result in a deadlock. Unfortunately there is no way to cancel a synchronous request on client-side (at least none that I'm aware of), so you should always keep synchronous requests short as possible (server side processing time). And to make sure, that you have a fast and reliable server, but you should always have that anyways^^.

---

*<sub>Be aware though, that some browsers (e.g. Opera) do **not** fire the `onunload` event, when specific browsers button are used.</sub>